# My business address isn't showing in Google Place ID

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, review

I know this question has been asked beforehand, and I was wondering whether someone could tell me my Google Place ID because I have followed other answers but had no luck, I want it so that I can post a review link.

This is my business on maps - https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Demeanour+Customs/@52.378986,0.932232,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xd69e990a1537e44d?sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjssorKvvTUAhWsCsAKHXdKB9MQ_BIIYDAK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the call to:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Demeanour%20Customs&key=YourKey

We get the following results, your place id is highlighted:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "Common Road, Hopton IP22 2QU, United Kingdom",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 52.378986,
               "lng" : 0.9322319999999998
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 52.38033498029149,
                  "lng" : 0.9335809802915019
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 52.37763701970849,
                  "lng" : 0.9308830197084978
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "690b7ddc30ccef065dcc64e46ce0e2ad7936d977",
         "name" : "Demeanour Customs",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 630,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/108914736063426931463/photos\"\u003eDemeanour Customs\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAoYmW_yjX5k5Q8Ra8gJsBputCHubMK0lo6SF73fNr1-isx7pVBqy4To8dXpXr3ECirXel_pKjD44CrDWVb6vqw6xKLc7AV4tErTEwgL5UnjizAyTrcRTfObgTpOyuOHGaEhDPpsShhN6jGTvzZT08zVtNGhRFUxbPiXSNnpTCs1JrVZdSq7HCtg",
               "width" : 1702
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJDVPTd0rI2UcRTeQ3FQqZntY",
         "reference" : "CmRSAAAAVXhOWK1IHyF8CKo_zjZtUVQXdFeNCCukCjiWE-X3JnEx0DdeJIDjXLpA4foqLDRZAVbPki72oM7tmhadvhAwlnBAGRljRdC8EVTbxjBxj8eDd-xZikpx7fNDaoCQFMIeEhAHIvtNywS7nsI3MZ5Vvi94GhTBFsCNb_a8g7TxDlbNvPBapJC4vQ",
         "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**"place_id" : "ChIJDVPTd0rI2UcRTeQ3FQqZntY",**